# Xfce panel buttons don't minimize windows when focus follows mouse is set

Tags: xfce, window-management

I like to have the focus follow my mouse, but I also like to be able to both minimize and restore windows by clicking the window button in the panel.

If "click to focus" is set, then I get that behaviour. If I change to "focus follows mouse", then the behaviour of the window buttons is a bit unpredictable.

Sometimes if I click to focus one window, then click another, then the second window minimizes while staying in the background.

Is this by design, or potentially a bug?

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.2 and haven't modified Xfce in any way.

Comment: There must be something in your configuration that produces that. I have Xfce 4.10 on Linux Mint 16 and have set "*Focus follows mouse*" with a rather short delay, not zero. Clicking window buttons in the panel does exactly what you describe, i.e. minimize/restore. Have you tried a focus delay greater than zero?

Comment: Yes, both my office machine and home are the same Xubuntu level, and I've noticed the same behaviour on both, even with different focus delays. I'm definitely on Xfce 4.10 too. I'll keep investigating the default configuration to see what it could be. I might try to reproduce in a VM or something.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any of «*Load KDE/Gnome services*» boxes checked in Xfce session settings?

Comment: In `Session and Startup` -> `Advanced` tab, I have `Launch GNOME services on startup` checked, but `Launch KDE services on startup` is unchecked. Could that be interfering?

Comment: It might be. Because I once had troubles with GNOME services and (IIRC) some keyboard settings, I've set myself to keep these unchecked. Try unchecking «*GNOME services*» and see what happens. Bear in mind that there might be some "cool" stuff that no longer works. But for test's sake...

Comment: If you're interested, I got to the root of the odd behaviour. It's something that I think is a bug with the way window buttons on panels handle focus. I've added more detail to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error on my part, I've worked out the behaviour of `focus-follows-mouse` on Xfce.

- When `focus-follows-mouse` is enabled, clicking the window button for each window will bring that window forward, but **not** give it focus.
- Clicking the window button of a **focused** window will minimize it, even if it's not at the front.brings it to the front, if it is minimized, else it will minimize the window.
- If the window is already brought to the front and **not** focused, then clicking the window button will do nothing

This seems like a bug to me, although some might argue it's working as designed. Either way, the root of the (apparent) unpredictability was that when `focus-follows-mouse` is enabled, window buttons on the panel do not affect the focus of the target window.

Comment: Well, congrats for digging it thus far. I for one never to rarely use window buttons and almost exclusively rely on auto focus using the mouse so I never observed the weirdness you described. Indeed this is worth trying to submit a bug for this.

Answer (score 1):

When customizing your desktop, there are chances you will accidentally lose some preferred functionalities either triggered by other actions you make or just that you did something and have forgotten how to reverse it.

Well, in case **minimize on panel click** is not working for you on Xfce (**maximize on panel click** always works), that is because you have set the option to minimize windows using middle click.

Here is how to reverse it.

-- Right-click an empty space on the panel and choose **Panel > Panel Preferences > Items**. Locate and select **Windows Buttons** and click on the **settings icon** at the bottom next to **Remove**. To achieve this easily, you can as well just hold down the **Ctrl key** then right-click on the **Windows Button** on the panel and choose **Properties**.

Look for **Middle click action** drop-down in the **Behaviour** section and change it to anything other than **Minimize Window**.

That's all.[image]